# Storing Value from a Query PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am working on a PHP MYSQL Project. I want to store result from a query into variable so that i can use it in my code.
The Query is written below.

```
$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Age FROM Employee where EmpID = '$_POST[empid]'");
```

This Query will output the following

```
Age
27
```

Kindly tell me how to store this value 27 in a variable lets say $Num.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result));
$age = $row['Age'];
```

To expand on this: If your query would return multiple rows you could iterate over them:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['Age'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Beware: never use POST variables directly without proper cleaning in your queries; it is very unsafe.
At least use [real escape string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Answer (score 1):

$result will return a mysql dataset.  You'll need to pull the value you need out of that dataset. I'm a PDO man but if memory serves

```
$Num = mysqli_fetch_assoc('Age');
```

will get you what you need.

I advise against beginning variables with a capital letter - it breaks most coding standards and could be confused with class names. And you really, really shouldn't send unsanitised POST variables to the database.

Comment: That also Correct, But gave best answer to person who posted the right first

Answer (score 0):

`$num = $result;` Although you're better off just using `$result`

Or long winded (but handy if there is more than 1 value you're trying to get)

```
foreach ($result as $r):
    $Num = $r['Age'];
endoforeach;
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$result=mysqli_result(mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Age FROM Employee where EmpID = '$_POST[empid]'"),0); 
$num=$result;

echo $num;
```

Answer (score 0):

After this line

```
$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Age FROM Employee where EmpID = '$_POST[empid]'");
```

ADD

```
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
 $Num=$row['Age'];
```

Thanks